# Why can't I var a = someFn.call; a();?

Tags: javascript, prototype, call, typeerror

This seems contradictory...in Chrome console:

```
> var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach.call;

> forEach
  function call() { [native code] }

> Object.getPrototypeOf(forEach);
  function () {}

> forEach([1,2,3], function(a) { console.log(a); });
  Uncaught TypeError: forEach is not a function
```

I'm guessing in JS internals function.call is not treated exactly like an ordinary function?

Comment: Because of how `this` works in JavaScript, `someFunction.call` is just `Function.prototype.call`. You probably want `.bind` which sets the `this` value - so `Array.prototype.forEach.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are first class citizens, just like strings and ints.  When you do, `Array.prototype.forEach.call`, you are getting the *value* of the `.call` property, which going up the `prototype` chain is `Function.prototype.call`.  So, your `forEach` variable is set to `Function.prototype.call`.

Now, when you *call* a function, the value of `this` inside that function is based upon how it's called.  When you do `forEach(...)`, it's like doing `Function.prototype.call.call(null)`.  `call` expects `this` to be a function and it's not, so it throws an error.

You probably want the following:

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
forEach.call([1,2,3], function(a) { console.log(a); });
```

Or maybe:

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach.bind([1,2,3]);
forEach(function(a) { console.log(a); });
```

Comment: It was the error that threw me off :)  This error is even worse: `Array.prototype.forEach()` `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function(...)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this too, if you want to do `forEach(array, fn)`

```
var forEach = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);
```

Now you can use it as you were doing it before:

```
forEach([1,2,3], function(a) { console.log(a); });
```

What you are doing is binding call `this` to `Array.prototype.forEach`. This is just a shorthand to write `Array.prototype.forEach.call`.

It's easier if you visualize how call "invokes" the function, so imagine call function does this (is not really like this):

```
return this(arg1, arg2, etc);
```

Now suppose `bind` returns the call function with a binding of `this` to `Array.prototype.forEach.call`:

```
return Array.prototype.forEach.call(arg1, arg2, etc);
```

You can of course, do the same thing yourself:

```
var forEach = function(array, fn) {
    return Array.prototype.forEach.call(array, fn);
}
```

Although I'm not sure which one would be better, performance wise.

Answer (score 2):

Functions that relies on `this` internally must be bound to work properly when detached from their "owner", because for unbound functions the `this` value will be the object referenced by the left-side of the dot in `obj.func()`. If functions are invoked directly from the current scope (e.g. `func()`) then `this` will point to `window`.

Therefore in the code below the `this` value when invoking `forEach` will be `window` while you need it to be `Array.prototype.forEach`.

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach.call;

forEach([1, 2], function () {}); //this inside forEach is window
```

To fix that problem we can bind `call` to `Array.prototype.forEach`.

```
   var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);

   forEach([1, 2, 3], function (num) {
       console.log(num);
   });
```